# Windows 10: most data hidden in "other files" after hard disk crash

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk

After a bad case of hard disk crash, I copied over all readable data using `dd` to an identical disk, then ran `chkdsk /F /X` until it said that there is nothing left to repair.

Unfortunately I couldn't get Windows to repair itself, so I reinstalled. It moved the previous version of windows to `WINDOWS.OLD` as usual. Now I have a running Windows 10, but most of the data isn't anywhere to be found. The disk has about 600 GB used up by "other files", but where are these? Under Unix/Linux, after repair that would go to lost+found, but in Windows? I have no idea...

(I known absolutely nothing about Windows, I'm a Linux user)

Comment: i assume, while disk crash you got registry broken. So in that case, windows cannot recognize is this problem install or not. In that particular case,  he can't understand so counts as 'other files'. You just need to make a fresh install of those  programs and reimport all that is safe.

Comment: @Reborn the data is invisible, nowhere to be found, even after turning off "hide hidden files", "hide windows system files", etc. No programs, no folders, no user files, nothing.

Comment: Look for a folder called "found.000" it may be a hidden fodler. Bear in mind that these are not files *per se* but recovered portions of files.

Comment: One easy way to get a visual of the disk structure is to use a "disk treemap" program.

Comment: Oh... now i get it. you need to 'heal' the hdd. first run hdd regenerator (if that is hdd, to restore damaged sectors) and after - recover all data with Recuva (not 100%, but in most cases it recovers) all possible data

Comment: @Reborn I've replicated the failing HDD to another one already. OK, I'll try Recuva.